# Does DocBook provide tag for genre of document?

Tags: semantic-markup, docbook

I use DocBook 5.0 for non technical book and I know that some other formats provide tags for genre of book (for example [fb2](http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/Eng:FictionBook_2.1_genres)) but I can not find such in DocBook.
May be I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such **exact** tag in DocBook 5.0 (5.1) itself, but they are (and even much more adopted to non-technical content) in so called DocBook Publishers Schema. For general information follow this link: http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/publishers/5.0/index.html

DocBook Publishers Schema allows you to use Dublin Core elements within `info` tag (i.e. `type` for genre). See details at: http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/publishers/5.0/ch02.html